# NSOutputStream (TCP) hangs indefinitely on stream:write after refactoring code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some code for writing/reading over a TCP NSStream. I refactored it, and now the `NSOutputStream:write` hangs indefinitely. Spent hours looking at it, can't crack it. I see the TCP SYN->ACK process happening fine - and I went back to the old version to test, and it still works (so the device on the other end is fine).

Everything is done on a single thread (stream creation, delegate, reading/writing, etc) which is not the main thread. Threading did not change in the refactoring at all.

Here is the code to create the streams (no change in refactoring):

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)_cam.IP, PTPIP_PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
_mainInputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
_mainOutputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[_mainInputStream setDelegate:self];
[_mainOutputStream setDelegate:self];

[_mainInputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // common mode!
[_mainOutputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // common mode!
[_mainInputStream open];
[_mainOutputStream open];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Here is the new code that fails while writing, it hangs on stream:write. When I check the stream status right before the write call, the stream is open (good). I also debugged the input to the function before & after the refactoring, there is no difference (good). I also thought to check for stream delegate's  `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`, but that appears to NEVER be thrown for either the old (working) or new (broken) code, so I guess it isn't applicable for TCP streams the way I'm using them. Other stream delegate events like NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable are being thrown just fine...

```
- (int)write:(const unsigned char*)bytes size:(unsigned int)size {

unsigned int bytesToWrite = size;

while( bytesToWrite > 0) {

    unsigned int chunkSize = (bytesToWrite > PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN)?PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN:bytesToWrite;

    // welcome to hangsville, population YOU
    int result = [self.myWorker.mainOutputStream write:bytes+(size-bytesToWrite) maxLength:chunkSize];

    if( result <= 0 )
        return PTP_ERROR_IO;
    bytesToWrite -= result;
}

return size-bytesToWrite;
}
```

Here's the old code that somehow works, even though input is the same...

```
static short
ptpip_write_func (unsigned char *bytes, unsigned int size, void *data)
{
PTPCamera* cam = (__bridge PTPCamera*)data;

unsigned int bytesToWrite = size;

while( bytesToWrite > 0) {

    unsigned chunkSize = (bytesToWrite > PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN)?PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN:bytesToWrite;
    unsigned char chunk[chunkSize];
    memcpy(chunk, bytes+(size-bytesToWrite), chunkSize);

    int result = [cam.outStream write:chunk maxLength:chunkSize];
    if( result <= 0 )
        return PTP_ERROR_IO;
    bytesToWrite -= result;
}

return PTP_RC_OK;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of debugging I concluded that there was really nothing different happening between the two versions, and that it must have been a fluke that it was *ever* working.

Sure enough, after additional researching I figured out that having stream open call on any thread OTHER than main is not going to work.

Here is the updated code, that works:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)cam.IP, PTPIP_PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
worker.mainInputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
worker.mainOutputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[worker.mainInputStream setDelegate:worker];
[worker.mainOutputStream setDelegate:worker];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [worker.mainInputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [worker.mainOutputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [worker.mainInputStream open];
    [worker.mainOutputStream open];
});
```